# css issue- span and anchor causing extra margin even with no height or width

Tags: css, anchor, margin, html

Driving me crazy...

Overlay-thats-absolutely-positioned

Span/anchor/image-thats-absolutely-positioned

span and anchor are set to `width:0;height:0;margin:0;` and still they offset the image by a few pixels

(if you highlight the overlay it's obvious)

CSS Gurus??

http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/aBWn6/1/

Comment: What on Earth are you asking here?

Comment: Your code drove me crazy too! You need to clean up your code and do better positioning!!

Comment: Likely you have content (such as a space) inside the element that prevents a width and height smaller than the text, but frankly I'm not browsing through all that to try and figure it out exactly.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks - title of the post.

Comment: @Mohsen - trying to work around a plugin the spits out ugly code (hence the span/anchor/image combo).

Comment: @animuson - commented the section I'm referencing. But that's cool.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `display: block;` to their CSS. The width and height are ignored for inline elements.